# Capturing WndProc message of a certain button click

Tags: winforms, .net-2.0, wndproc, windows-messages

I have a cancel button on my form. I want to determine inside the `WndProc` method that this `Cancel` button is clicked and write some code for it. This is absolutely necessary because otherwise I'm not able to cancel all other control validation events that are yet to be performed.

Please help.

.NET - 2.0, WinForms

Comment: C# or VB?  Also, do you know at runtime where the button is on the form?

Comment: Well, of course it is not absolutely necessary and overriding the form's WndProc() method certainly won't get you anywhere.  Consider setting the button's CausesValidation property to False and using the form's FormClosing event to set e.Cancel back to false.

Comment: @C.Barlow Anyone would do. Yes it is at a fixed position on my form.

Comment: @HansPassant First of all I'm not closing the form in case of clicking the button, I'm only resetting the form controls. And if there are controls which failed validation then `CauseValidation` does not help. It the validation is always performed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how you could parse the WndProc message for a left-click on a child control:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh454920(v=vs.85).aspx
    // 0x210 is WM_PARENTNOTIFY
    // 513 is WM_LBUTTONCLICK
    if (m.Msg == 0x210 && m.WParam.ToInt32() == 513) 
    {
        var x = (int)(m.LParam.ToInt32() & 0xFFFF);
        var y = (int)(m.LParam.ToInt32() >> 16);

        var childControl = this.GetChildAtPoint(new Point(x, y));
        if (childControl == cancelButton)
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

BTW: this is 32-bit code.

Comment: Will there be major changes for 64 bit?

Comment: An IntPtr will be 64 bits when compiling for the .NET 64 bit. As far as I know this could should still work but I didn't test it. BTW: I fixed an error in the code (replaced 0xFF by 0xFFFF)

Comment: This absolutely works in regular windows component, but when using DevExpress there is control called LayoutControl whose child control is this button. So when clicking the child control always returns the LayoutControl instead of the button. Any ideas of how to work around this?

Comment: The only solution I can see is to try and find the hwnd of the control you are interested in and spy the messages. Have a look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163617.aspx

Comment: Will try something and let you know.

Answer (score 3):

> And if there are controls which failed validation then CauseValidation does not help

Well, sure it does, that's what the property was designed to do.  Here's an example form to show this at work.  Drop a textbox and a button on the form.  Note how you can click the button to clear the textbox, even though the box always fails its validation.  And how you can close the form.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        textBox1.Validating += new CancelEventHandler(textBox1_Validating);
        button1.Click += new EventHandler(button1_Click);
        button1.CausesValidation = false;
        this.FormClosing += new FormClosingEventHandler(Form1_FormClosing);
    }

    private void textBox1_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e) {
        // Always fail validation
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
    void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        // Your Cancel button
        textBox1.Text = string.Empty;
    }
    void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e) {
        // Allow the form to close even though validation failed
        e.Cancel = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well I'm using DevExpress components and I can tell you for sure that it does not work in that. If you can show me how to use `WndProc` to do the same, it would be really helpful.

Comment: I can't help you with that, contact DevExpress for support.

Comment: A simple `WndProc` example would do of how to know which message originated from that button click.