# Handle Double Click Anywhere in the Form?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

In my WinForm application I have drawn a rectangle (System.Drawing.Rectangle) on a form.

> I need to handle double click anywhere on the form

I could attach `MouseDoubleClick` event handler to the form. It works only when double click was made outside the rectangular shape.

How do I achieve this?

**EDIT:**

I have drawn a rectangle which is center aligned and covers only 40% of the whole winform area. When user double clicks on the rectangle I need to expand rectangle size to occupy full screen. That's all!

**EDIT 2:**

My friends who have down voted, write a comment please so that I could improve, please!

Comment: Could you please elaborate on `but that works only when double click was outside the rectangle`? I suppose you're not drawing it in form. presumably you're having a panel control in place or...

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I have drawn the rectangle on the form, rectangle does not occupy full area of form.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel when click is made on the shape `MouseDoubleClick` is  not triggered.

Comment: If that is the case it should have worked. Post your code so that we can see where you're wrong.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel The code was as simple as:: select winform in designer view >> Press F4 to go to property pages >> Locate `MouseDoubleClick` entry press enter. It creates an event handler.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I set a break point on this event handler. Break point hits only when:- I click outside rectangle (but on form of course)

Comment: It'd really helpful if you posted the relevant code (yours as well as the generated one).

Comment: If you can give some reproduction code which explains the problem I'd help. Right now it's hard to guess. Post a repro.

Answer (score 1):

The best way I know to do what you are looking for is to use the "WndProc" method. This allows you to collect "messages" (events) from the message queue before they are sent to the form. You then have the option of either responding to those events or allowing them to continue through the normal message process. For more information, take a look at the [MSDN page here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.wndproc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

A brief example of how you might use this:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh454920(v=vs.85).aspx
    // 0x210 is WM_PARENTNOTIFY
    // 513 is WM_LBUTTONCLICK
    if (m.Msg == 0x210 && m.WParam.ToInt32() == 513) 
    {
        var x = (int)(m.LParam.ToInt32() & 0xFFFF);
        var y = (int)(m.LParam.ToInt32() >> 16);

        var childControl = this.GetChildAtPoint(new Point(x, y));
        if (childControl == cancelButton)
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

Credit for this example goes to: [this stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10635518/capturing-wndproc-message-of-a-certain-button-click).

Remember too, that "double click" is just two single clicks, so you are going to have to monitor and find the time between clicks yourself to decide what actually represents a double click.

Comment: "decide what actually represents a double click" -- Do you know if there's a standard for that time difference? Or perhaps should that be a question on UX.SE?

Comment: I'm no expert at UX/UI, but according to wikipedia [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-click) `The maximum delay required for two consecutive clicks to be interpreted as a double-click is not standardized`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Rectangle does not contain any fire any events (at all) as System.Drawing merely provides "grahpics" for a form.

There are options (such as provided by @drew_w) however such workarounds that require interaction with COM objects is usually indicate it's time to re-evaluate the requirements.

Comment: I have drawn a rectangle which is center aligned and covers only 40% of the whole winform area. When user double clicks on the rectangle I need to expand rectangle size to occupy full screen. That's all!